# Get Jenkins Pipeline lastBuild result in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use a Jenkinsfile (scripted pipeline) to send a slack message on a recovered build. I've tried using `lastBuild` but that isn't available. I was hoping there would be something along these lines.

```
if(lastBuild.result == "FAILURE") {
  slackSend(channel: '#ci', color: '#00ee00', message: "RECOVERED: ${env.JOB_NAME} - [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get from current pipeline build the previous one:

```
node {
  def lastBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()
  if( lastBuild && lastBuild.getResult().toString()=="FAILURE" ){
    println "the previous build ${lastBuild.getId()} failed"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately we're using the scripted pipeline for our Jenkinsfile. I don't think you can have that section in it.

Comment: If we were to be able to convert to declarative, how can you be sure it has changed from fail to success

Comment: do you mean you want to know in your next build the status of previous one?

Comment: yes, in build 2 i want to know if build 1 failed so that i can tell if it has recovered from a failure

Comment: changed the answer according to this info

Comment: thanks, do I need to do something to allow access to `rawBuild`? I got an error when I tried it

Comment: try `Manage Jenkins > In-process Script Approval`

Comment: thanks, works great! I had to approve the following: 

`method hudson.model.Run getPreviousBuild
method hudson.model.Run getResult
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild`